# Capturing height of parent DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, height

I have a web page with a number of `ul` lists. Each `ul` list is surrounded by a `div` with a class `.content`.

What i am trying to do, is get the height of the `.content DIV` when its corresponding `li` within a `ul` is clicked.

My code at the minute is only setting the height of the first `content DIV` on the page.

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="myList">
    <li>
        <div class="heading">
            <a>Menu 1</a>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
                <h2>Menu 1</h2>
            <ul class="show-hide">
                <li>
                    <a href="">How to reach us</a>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="">How to email us</a>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="">Contact Number</a>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="heading">
            <a>Menu 2</a>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
                <h2>Menu 2</h2>
            <ul class="show-hide">
                <li>
                    <a href="">How to reach us</a>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="heading">
            <a>Menu 3</a>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
                <h2>Menu 3</h2>
            <ul class="show-hide">
                <li>
                    <a href="">How to reach us</a>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="">How to email us</a>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="">Contact Number</a>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="">How to email us</a>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="">Contact Number</a>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('.show-hide').on('click', function () {

    getHeight = $('.content').height();

    alert(getHeight);

    return false;
});
```

My fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/oampz/BK7yw/

Any help appreciated

Comment: you can use `$(this).parent('.content').height()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `parents()` or `parent()`

```
   $('.show-hide').on('click', function () {

        getHeight = $(this).parents('.content').height();

        alert(getHeight);

        return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use [`jQuery#closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) as : `$(this).closest('.content').height()`;

**[JsFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/budhram/BK7yw/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

You just selected all the elements with the class name `content`. But your requirement is to select the element with the class `content` within the clicked element's context. so you have to prefer `$(this)` reference for that first, then try use `.closest()` to find the closest element with the supplied selector,

```
$('.show-hide').on('click', function () {
    getHeight = $(this).closest('.content').height(); 
    alert(getHeight);
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **.parents()** api https://api.jquery.com/parents/

```
 getHeight = $(this).parents('.content').height();
```